# Stop Edge from saving new personal info but allow it to autofill existing personal info

Tags: microsoft-edge, auto-form-fill, personal-data

Microsoft Edge has a feature where it can autofill my personal information whenever a website asks for my name, address, email, etc. This is often very useful, but one thing I find very annoying is that whenever I enter other information than my personal information in a field called "Name", "Address", "Email", etc it automatically saves that information as my personal information.

For example, some websites allow me to search for other people by name, but whenever I write something in the "Name" field, Edge saves the *other person's* name as *my* personal info. It doesn't even have to be a field asking for someone's personal info. For example, in [PhpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/), when I enter the name of a table or a column I want to create, Edge saves that as *my* name. I can manually delete it from the settings, but it's annoying to have to do that each time I enter a name that's not mine somewhere.

So I would like to stop Edge from saving new personal info. My name and email address will probably never change so I will never have to update that, and I don't move very often so I have nothing against updating my address manually in the settings next time I move.

I searched for how to do this, and found a lot of pages like [this one](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/160845-enable-disable-save-fill-personal-info-microsoft-edge.html) that tell me to go to `edge://settings/personalinfo` and turn off the "Save and fill personal info" checkbox at the top. While this stops the browser from saving personal info as I want, it also stops the browser from suggesting to fill personal info that I already saved.

Is there a way stop Edge from saving new personal info while still allowing it to autofill existing personal info?